# Using Jquery append() to build html and pass null javascript values

Tags: jquery, append

Here is my code:

$('#pageForward').append('
    detailUser +','+ detailDate +','+ detailUserName +
','+ previousPage +');"> >>');

The string builds, but if my variables are null, I get a syntax error:

[Break On This Error] getSDDetailPopUp(Accounting,,,,2);

How do I get this string to be this:
    getSDDetailPopUp(Accounting,'','','',2);

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building this string on the client or server side?

Answer (score 1):

use || as a null coalescing operator.

... `detailUser || "" +` ...

Comment: this did not work  $('#pageForward').append('<a href="#" onclick="getSDDetailPopUp('+ detailDept +','+ detailUser || "" +',' detailDate || "" +','+ detailUserName || "" +','+ nextPage +');"> >></a>');

Comment: It looks like you are building the jquery string on the serverside - we need to know what serverside technology\code you are using to build this string.  I suspect this is not really jquery\javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your params you can just do...

(detailUser != null ? detailUser : "''")